# Compare array of objects by property with key of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, underscore.js

I want to compare the **data.examples** array object **name.value** property **value** with **wcObject.notCoveredList** key, If the key matches I want to push *all matched values* of wcObject to an  array inorder to display in UI. If the key doesn't match, I want the **name.desc property** value of data.examples array object to be pushed by **removing** the *not covered* text at the end.

```
    data = {
        examples : [
          {
            name: {
              value:"someOne",
              desc: "some random word not covered"
            },
            type: {
              value:"General",
              desc:"General"
            }
          }, {
            name: {
              value:"secondOne",
              desc: "second on in the queue not covered"
            },
            type: {
              value:"General",
              desc:"General"
            }
          }, {
            name: {
              value:"thirdOne",
              desc: "third one from the last not covered"
            },
            type: {
              value:"General",
              desc:"General"
            }
          }
        ]

      }

 wcObject = {
    notCoveredList : [
      { someOne: "anyone can start " },
      { secondOne: "second One cannot start" },
      { thirdOne: "third One can be allowed" }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Simplier the better. There is interest neither in nesting exemples in data nor notCoveredList in wcObject. You should change this

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense, I think. Let me repeat it back to you and see if you can correct yourself or me where the misunderstanding lays... 'for every example: if name.value matches the key  of an object in wcObject.notCoveredList, push it to the output array--if it doesn't match a key, trim the 'not covered' off the end of the example's name.desc and push that instead'. The reason this doesn't make sense is that if you trim the 'not covered' off of the end, what you essentially end up doing is pushing the same as name.value, since name.value === name.desc + ' not covered'.

Comment: Sorry @kyle Baker, let me correct it. The name.desc value can be whatever text with not covered at the end.

Comment: @sriharsha, ok, so that was just a coincidence. In that case, is there any reason the answer I proposed is not sufficient? edit: I have updated it to include the string slicing bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this code:

1. Builds up a filter object. We grab all the keys of
   `wcObject.notCoveredList`, and make them keys on a single object (with
   an undefined value), so that we can look up those keys with a single
   hasOwnProperty() call instead of iterating over an array when we need to filter.
2. Maps every member of the `data.examples` array to either its own `name.desc` property or [stripped of ' not covered'] `name.value` property.

.

```
wcNotCoveredKeys = wcObject.notCoveredList.reduce((memo, item) => {
  // value is empty for all, we only care about keys.
  memo[Object.keys(item)[0]] = undefined;
  return memo;
}, {})

// having built up our lookup table of those not covered, we continue:
forUI = data.examples.map(example => {
  if (wcNotCoveredKeys.hasOwnProperty(example.name.value)) {
    return example.name.value;
  }
  else {
    notCoveredString = example.name.desc;
    cutOutIndex = notCoveredString.indexOf(' not covered');
    return notCoveredString.slice(0, cutOutIndex)
  }
});
```

(updated to integrate string slicing)

Just to be clear: if you removed the second item from wcObject.notCoveredList, then the output you'd get in forUI (given the example data structures/values you provided) would be

`["someOne", "second on in the queue", "thirdOne"]`